# Distances in a list

Tags: r

I have a list where each element is a data frame.

> `list[1]`

```
$`1`
      id   yr   mo   dy   hr   lon   lat 
     00020 1860 10   30    1    7.5  -42.
     00020 1860 10   30    2    7.6  -43.
     00020 1860 10   30    4    7.9  -44.
     00020 1860 10   30    5    8.2  -46.
```

I would like to add three extra column and calculate for each list

the spatial differences between two successive points
the temporal differences between two successive points
the correlation coefficient for the interpolating line

but only if two successive points have a temporal differences less than t* and otherwise put 0.

I known distances can be computed with geosphere but I am having some trouble to perform operation on lists.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you know how to do it for one `data.frame` then just use `lapply` on your list of `dats.frames`

e.g.

```
#create your new columns function as it would work for one data.frame

foo <- function(DF){
DF$new1 <- distm(x,y)....etc
DF$new2 <- .......etc
DF$new3 <- cor(x,y).......etc
return(DF)
}
```

Then lapply over the list to return a list of `data.frames` with the new columns:

```
DFlist <- list(DF1, DF2, DF3)

lapply(DFlist, foo)
```